# How to resize image tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, tensor

The following is my code where I'm converting every image to PIL and then turning them into Pytorch tensors:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.PILToTensor()])

# choose the training and test datasets
train_data = os.listdir('data/training/')
testing_data = os.listdir('data/testing/')
train_tensors = []
test_tensors = []

for train_image in train_data:
    img = Image.open('data/training/' + train_image)
    train_tensors.append(transform(img))

for test_image in testing_data:
    img = Image.open('data/testing/' + test_image)
    test_tensors.append(transform(img))

# Print out some stats about the training and test data
print('Train data, number of images: ', len(train_data))
print('Test data, number of images: ', len(testing_data))

batch_size = 20

train_loader = DataLoader(train_tensors, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_tensors, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# specify the image classes
classes = ['checked', 'unchecked', 'other']

# obtain one batch of training images
dataiter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
images = images.numpy()
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [4, 66, 268] at entry 0 and [4, 88, 160] at entry 1
```

This is because my images are not resized prior to PIL -> Tensor. What is the correct way of resizing data images?

Comment: You need to crop/pad/resize so the images all have the same size, but there's not really a "correct" way -- it depends on the context of your problem. You can customize the dataloader to do that, or just preprocess them all ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to utilize [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html#imagefolder) from `torchvision`, and assuming that images have diff size, you can use [CenterCrop](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop.html#torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop) or [RandomResizedCrop](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop) depending on your task. Check the [Full list](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#transforms-on-pil-image-and-torch-tensor).

Here is an example:

```py
train_dir = "data/training/"

train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
    train_dir,
    transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(img_size),  # image size int or tuple
        # Add more transforms here
        transforms.ToTensor(),  # convert to tensor at the end
]))

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```